# Laravel and Nginx static files

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, assets

So I am having a problem with getting Nginx to serve static files for my Laravel app. I can see in chrome's dev tools that the requests are being made to the path, where those files should be (http://mywebsite.com/public/css/style.css). But they are not being loaded at all. I've tried getting it to work in a lot of ways, but it just doesn't seem to do the job. Could anyone help me with that? Cheers!

```
  server {

    listen 80;

    server_name mydomainname.com;

    keepalive_timeout   70;
    root /var/www/html/portfolio/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    autoindex on;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/portfolio/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log error;

    sendfile on;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    rewrite ^ /index.php last;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Basically, there's a lot of files in /public directory that are not loading, but should be. Like for example css, js, html files for angular templates etc...

Comment: The first red flag is "public" it should not be there (eg: `example.com/css/whatever.css`).

Comment: you need to open up your logs (nginx ones) and read it. 500 is most likely permission problem but read the logs, maybe edit question and add tail of the log. If its 404 also take a look at laravels log. Also, do you access your page through... `public/index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kyslik hinted, this could be a permission problem.

I had a similar problem, running Laravel on Homestead on Windows 10. In my case, I could access the files from `public\css` directory, but not from `public\css\vendor`. I realized that I created the `vendor` directory from Windows, and as a result, the files in it were not accessible by ngingx.

To fix the issue I deleted the `vendor` directory and recreated it from within the vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

The urls don't need to include the `/public` part in the path. `/public` is the root for your web assets. So your url should be:

```
http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css
```

Comment: Yes, but when I do curl on such path, I get 404, that's why I think it's not being served at all

Comment: @AndrewPomorski Do you have folder `css` in `public` folder? And do you have style.css inside that folder?

Comment: @Kyslik yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is understanding the server is a different pc entirely and resolving path range for hosting service all around the global.

Best practice is to make sure your assets are only one step deeper into your application

Eg.

`<link href="folder/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` wrong

`<link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />` correct

The server will not stress scanning directory. and the server will only go one step deeper.

AWS Ec2 Instance Ubuntu x Laravel Application.